# help understanding probability

Tags: probability

Suppose I have three balls and eight urns lined up in a row. If I blindly throw balls to the urns in the row, what is the probability of 3 balls ending on the same urn? What is the probability of 2 balls ending on the same urn and the next one on other urn? Assume that ball won't go outside of urn in any throw & my throw is also not biased. I am unable to grasp the concept of probability properly. Any hints would be appreciated.

P.S. This is not a homework problem. :)

Comment: There are only $8^3 = 512$ possible way to distribution three (distinguishable) balls over 8 urns. If you lack a better idea, you can always list them all (using, for example, excel), and figure out how many of them have all the three balls in the same urn.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say your throws are not biased, it means that they are independent of one another. Firstly, the chance of you throwing all three balls in the same urn would be $(\frac{1}{8})^2$. This is because independent events have this property: If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. This is incredibly useful, as we can find the probability of rolling a 5 on a six sided dice (1/6) and then rolling a 4 (1/6).

$P(5\cap 6)=P(5)P(6)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$.

In your case we are throwing the first ball into any one of the urns, so the chance of the first ball doing that is 1. Next we want the second ball to go into that same urn, so that chance is $1/8$, and finally we want the final ball to also go in that same urn, again with a probability of $1/8$. We want to find the probability of ALL these three independent events happening, so we are trying to find

$P(1\cap 2\cap 3)=P(1)P(2)P(3)=1.\frac{1}{8}.\frac{1}{8}=(\frac{1}{8})^2=\frac{1}{64}$.

(You can also answer that question with the binomial model if you have learned that :) )

For your second question, the first two balls going into the same urn and the last one going into another, then we have the three events; 1- throwing a ball into an urn $P(1)=1$, 2- throwing a ball into that same urn $P(2)=\frac{1}{8}$, and 3- throwing the last ball into a different urn $P(3)=?$.

Now you just need to find the chance of throwing a ball into any of the other urns, but not the one already containing two balls, then use the independence law given above and you should have your answer.

hope this helps  :)

Comment: In summary: probability of 3 urns each with 1 ball, 5 empty, is 21/32. Probability of 1 urn with 1 and one urn with 2 balls, 6 empty, is 21/64, and probability of 1 urn with 3 balls, 7 empty, is 1/64.

Answer (score 0):

To count equally probably arrangements, consider both the balls and urns to be distinct.

Count the ways to select 3 balls from 3, times the ways to select 1 urn from 2 to place them in.  $\,^3C_3\times\,^2C_1=2$

Count the total number of ways three balls can each be distributed into either of two urns.  $2^3$

Divide an conquer.  $P(\text{3 in one}) = \frac 1 4$

---

Count the ways to select two balls from 3, times the ways to select 1 urn from 2 (the remaining ball goes to the remaining urn): $\,^3C_2\times\,^2C_1 = 6$

Same total number of ways.

Divide an conquer.  $P(\text{2 in one, 1 in other}) = \frac 3 4$

(Or you could just note that they are mutually exclusive and exhaustive events, so the sum or probabilities must be $1$.)